# Can't start httpd in my Centos6

Tags: linux, centos

Yesterday it was starting normally but now it doesn't work

```
[root@dnsmaster ~]# service httpd start

Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 203 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_unique_id.so# into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_unique_id.so#: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
                                                           [FAILED]
```

This is the line 203 of the file

```
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so#
```

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the `#` at the end.

Correct:

```
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
```

Comment: [root@dnsmaster ~]# service httpd start                                                                                                        
Starting httpd: [Sun Apr 26 22:58:26 2020] [warn] module security2_module is already loaded, skipping
Syntax error on line 23 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/modsecurity.conf:
ModSecurity: Found another rule with the same id
                                                           [FAILED]

Comment: it doesn't work :( :(